# Derivative of trace of log of matrix products w.r.t. a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Is there a way to calculate $$\frac{\partial\; \mbox{tr}\{\log(X^tBX)\}}{\partial X},$$ where $X$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices?

Answer (score 4):

$${\rm tr}\log (X^t B X)=\log{\rm det}\,(X^t BX)=2\log{\rm det}\,X+\log{\rm det}\,B$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{\partial}{\partial X}{\rm tr}\log (X^t B X)=2X^{-1},$$
in view of [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

Comment: Yes! Thanks! There is a bit mess with transposes, but I can fix it (X is not symmetric).

Comment: it doesn't matter if X is symmetric or not, since the determinant of X is the same as the determinant of its transpose

Comment: Would be great if such questions were routed to math.SE :-)  (including say the slightly more interesting version with a rectangular $X$)